# Everlasting Android service -IDEA-

Tags: android, service, task

I am making an anti-theft app for Android.

My app should listen for SMS and get commands from a text message (erase phone content - send location ... )

i'm facing the problem of my app getting killed by Android

i had made some researches i found some ideas like "alarm that check the app every 5 mins"

and sticky_function and much more. some people just stay it is not possible
the problem is that it must not be ever killed

I believe that android always kill background apps but it never kill a foreground app.
so i have an idea : it is to make a transparent app that will be always be in the foreground and it mirrors every thing behind it and send touches to what ever app is behind it (the app that the user is currently seeing)

imagine it like when u use and emulator on a PC 
the host takes the mouse clicks and redirect them to the guest OS

is this possible ?

if not , is it possible i make my app as a system service like (phone - SMS - GPS) so it will never be killed ?

i was wondering how do antivirus apps keep monitoring every thing and not being killed with system or 3rd parity task killers ?

Answer (score 2):

> is this possible ?

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> if not , is it possible i make my app as a system service like (phone - SMS - GPS) so it will never be killed ?

You can create your own ROM mod that has your app in it.

> i was wondering how do antivirus apps keep monitoring every thing and not being killed with system or 3rd parity task killers ?

AFAIK, antivirus apps can be force-stopped, just like anything else.

However, your original assumption is incorrect:

> i'm facing the problem of my app getting killed by Android

You do not need to be running in order to receive SMS messages. That is handled by a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. The only time your process needs to be running is when a text message comes in, so that you can process it. Ordinary OS behavior, and task killers, will not affect this. If the user force-stops you (e.g., through Settings), that *will* affect you, just like any other app, and there is nothing you can really do about that.

Note, though, that you will want to find some other trigger mechanism than SMS, as [as of Android 4.4](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), all other apps will be able to see your SMS, including the user, when the SMS appears in their inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Android Service.. these are not killed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

And there's a good tutorial here..

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html